# Asyncio graceful shutdown for a pushing server

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Consider (where `queue` is an `asyncio.Queue`, and I'm using the asyncio [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) library which uses the same server interface as `asyncio` in the standard library):

```
async def handler(websocket: websockets.WebSocketServerProtocol, path):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send(data)
```

What I'm finding is that the `ConnectionClosed` exception (triggered either when a client disconnects, and is also used for server shutdown) is only raised, obviously, within the loop when we are awaiting on `send()`.  This can happen **long** after a websocket client has disconnected, because we will spend most of the time awaiting on `queue.get()`.

Furthermore, I'm trying to implement graceful shutdown of the server.  That code looks very similar to the standard

```
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
```

The issue is that my websocket handler, i.e., `handler()`, nevertheless still continues to wait on the `queue` for more data before raising the exceptions that `wait_closed()` placed on the event loop.

My **question**: is it correct to introduce the use of `wait_for()` to make the `handler()` function more responsive to these management events:

```
async def handler(websocket: websockets.WebSocketServerProtocol, path):
    while True:
        try:
            data = await loop.wait_for(queue.get(), 5.0)  # 5 seconds
            await websocket.send(data)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            logging.debug('Refreshing the loop')
```

Most of the asyncio examples I've found online have been quite simplistic and don't seem to cover these kinds of issues.

I *could* also put junk on the queue during my shutdown sequence, which would allow the exception to be raised, but that wouldn't help catching client disconnections earlier.

Any good references with examples would be much appreciated. I'm finding the official asyncio docs somewhat terse.

Comment: This might be helpfull 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604033/waiting-for-a-task-to-complete-after-keyboardinterrupt-in-asyncio
The answer is more generic than the question.

Comment: To answer short, `await queue.get()` is doomed, you application will throw exception on shutdown. And queue.get() with timeout, is mem leaking atm http://bugs.python.org/issue26259. Use queue.get_nowait() with try/except. That is the way to go ;) I am working on a patch for the mem leak problem at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That memory issue is very interesting and something I definitely hadn't considered. If you would be willing to create an answer showing the code for how to use `get_nowait()` in an idiomatic way (I think it would help others reading this) I'll accept your answer 

Comment: Now i read my comment again, of cause it will not throw exception, but it will tell you that you have pending coroutines. ;)

Comment: Did you read the other answer i wrote, which I linked to in the first comment?

Comment: Yes. If you're busy that's fine, I can write an answer here more specific to my question.  Thanks again for your help.