# Waiting for a task to complete after KeyboardInterrupt in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand how does `asyncio` work. In my scenario client makes a `tcp` connection to the server, sends a login string, if authenticated - receives a stream of chars. Finally on `KeyboardInterrupt` sends `logoff` string to the server and hapilly disconnects.

Currently I'm stuck on the final part as my logoff method/task is destroyed before it has a chance to complete.

```
^CTask was destroyed but it is pending!
source_traceback: Object created at (most recent call last):
  File "tst.py", line 101, in <module>
    client.login()
  File "tst.py", line 29, in login
    logoff_tsk = self.loop.create_task(self.logoff())
task: <Task pending coro=<logoff() running at tst.py:49> cb=[myClass._shutdown()] created at tst.py:29>
```

Below is the code which produces this error:

```
from functools import partial
import asyncio

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        self.transport = None
        self.protocol = None
        self.usr = str(kw.get("usr", ""))
        self.pwd = str(kw.get("pwd", ""))
        self.host = str(kw.get("host", "")) or "127.0.0.2"
        self.port = int(kw.get("port", 0)) or 5038
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.set_debug(enabled=True)

    def reactor(self, recv):
        print("## ~/~ From reactor: {!r}".format(recv.decode()))

    def login(self):
        connection_tsk = self.loop.create_task(self.loop.create_connection(
            partial(
                myProtocol,
                reactor_func=self.reactor),
            host=self.host,
            port=self.port))
        connection_tsk.add_done_callback(self.set_transport_protocol)
        try:
            self.loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logoff_tsk = self.loop.create_task(self.logoff())
            logoff_tsk.add_done_callback(self._shutdown)

    def set_transport_protocol(self, fut):
        print("AmiCtl.set_transport_protocol")
        transport, protocol = fut.result()
        self.transport = transport
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.loop.call_soon(self._login)

    def _login(self):
        login_string = self.cmd("Login")
        self.loop.create_task(self.transmit(login_string))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def transmit(self, cmd):
        if self.transport:
            print("## ~/~ Sending data: {!r}".format(cmd))
            self.transport.write(cmd)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def logoff(self):
        command = self.cmd("Logoff")
        yield from asyncio.shield(self.transmit(command))

    def _shutdown(self):
        if self.transport:
            self.transport.close()
        self.loop.stop()
        self.loop.close()
        print("\n{!r}".format(self.loop))

    def cmd(self, action):
        """
        Produce login/logoff string.
        """

class myProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, reactor_func=None):
        self.reactor_func = reactor_func
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        peername = transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        print("## ~/~ Connection made: {peer}".format(peer=peername))

    def data_received(self, data):
        if callable(self.reactor_func):
            self.reactor_func(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print("## ~/~ Lost connection to the server!!")
        self.loop.stop()


client = myClass(usr="my_usr", pwd="my_pwd")
client.login()
```

How can I improve/fix my code please?

Comment: You forgot to run the event loop after creating the `logoff` task.

Comment: I'm running the `loop` with the `run_forever()` which essentially should keep the `loop` alive until `stop()` is called. The only place where `stop()` is called is in the in the `_shutdown()` callback. I'm trying to protect my last call of `transmit()` with `asyncio.shield()`, but that obviously does not work, `logoff` returns/yields before `transmit` completes its operations and therefore `_shutdown` is called to soon. This is my view of the problem, that I'm facing.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` actually stops the loop, and `shield` only protects from cancellation.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I did not realize that `KeyboardInterrupt` was killing the loop and can't remember it being documented. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is and http://xyproblem.info, the real question is how to controlled shut down asyncio application with loose tasks pending. And the question could go further, why are tasks pending. So the question is, how do I do task management in asyncio and ensure clean shutdown. I wrote you a generic answer, but please think about how you ask questions. :)

Comment: btw `asyncio.shield` is not a good idea in your usecase as i read the code. The only thing it does is to make you lose control, as you are now not able to cancel the underlying coroutine. That is not what you want, in regard to controlled shutdown it actually works againt you :(

You should NOT do the `except KeyboardInterrupt` when working with ascynio code use signal handlers instead.

Answer (score 5):

I will not refer to you code as I think your question is a xy-question. (http://xyproblem.info), But I will try to answer in a more generic way. What I am reading is that you are asking how to correctly close down an asyncio application.

I have set up a small example that I think with some explanation will get you on the right track. Read the code below, my hope is that it can relate to your use case and I will explain below.

```
import asyncio
import signal

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


class Connector:

    def __init__(self):
        self.closing = False
        self.closed = asyncio.Future()
        task = loop.create_task(self.connection_with_client())
        task.add_done_callback(self.closed.set_result)


    async def connection_with_client(self):
        while not self.closing:
            print('Read/write to open connection')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        print('I will now close connection')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


conn = Connector()


def stop(loop):
    conn.closing = True
    print("from here I will wait until connection_with_client has finished")
    conn.closed.add_done_callback(lambda _: loop.stop())

loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, stop, loop)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

What you are asking for is actually not trivial, one of the hardest things to manage doing asyncio is correctly closing an asyncio application.

To do managed closing you have to have a coroutine in place that will handle shutdown and set af future as done, when it has made sure that everything is shutdown. In my example it is `task.add_done_callback(self.closed.set_result)` but this future could be set in other ways.

Second, you have to add a signal handler that will run a non-asynchronously (normal) function and schedule a callback, that triggers the loop to close/stop when your 'close future' is done.

Take a look at my code and toy around with it until you understand the flow. I dont blame you for asking, in my opinion one of the hardest things doing asyncio is to keep track of 'loose' coroutines, that will result in unclean shutdown.

When I did this 'exercise' my first time and needed to understand the principles I went though the code of https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis/blob/master/aioredis/connection.py#L93-L95
If you take the time to read the code these guys handle your exact problem in a very beautiful way, I know the code is a but complex, but take a mug of coffee and follow the method calls around until it makes sense.

I hope this helps you, post more details or comments if I am unclear. And take you time to understand this topic (the asycnio shutdown things). When you master shutdown management with asyncio you are not a asyncio-padawan anymore ;)

You may think, Thats alot of code to shutdown clean, but to my understanding, this is the way to do it(and more or less the only way for bigger and more complex applications).

Best of luck.

Comment: For production code you also need a `SIGTERM` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation! Long story short - you are saying, that I catch signals incorrectly? I accept that, indeed with `add_signal_handler()` I don't have to restart the loop. But I don't like your `while not` solution. With this I would potentially have had to add `asyncio.Queue` to the mix and I don't need this, as my protocol reads from the socket asynchroneously, `transport.write` writes to the socket in async fashion too. So the last thing I want here is more `coroutines` and `futures`.

Comment: this helped me out of a bind, together with [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987985/asyncio-loops-add-signal-handler-in-windows). Thanks!