# asyncio loop's add_signal_handler() in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm currently porting a Python project from Linux to Windows (using Anaconda Python 3.6). Everything works perfectly, I just cannot get a graceful exit of the asyncio loop working.

In Linux I'm doing the following:

```
class GracefulExit(SystemExit):
    code = 1

def raise_graceful_exit():
    raise GracefulExit()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, raise_graceful_exit)
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, raise_graceful_exit)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except GracefulExit:
    pass

shutdown()
```

In Windows, unfortunately I get a `NotImplementedError` on `add_signal_handler`. Without this, of course I never get a chance for a clean shutdown of the program.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: See [issue 23057](http://bugs.python.org/issue23057).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows does not have signals.

If the process gets killed via the TerminateProcess API, you do not get any chance to cleanup (its like 'kill -9', blows your process away).

But windows has two ways to signal if your code should exit, one for console programs (e.g. python.exe) and one for gui programs (pythonw.exe).

Python automatically handles the console thing and raises a KeyboardInterrupt exception, but you can hook your own code into that handler with the console control handler APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-control-handlers), but thats probably overkill. Just set a proper exception handler on your event loop.

For GUI processes, Windows sends you windows messages, like [WM_QUIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641(v=vs.85).aspx) or various others if a user logs off, system goes to power saving mode etc., you can handle those too, with the help of ctypes or the win32 package, or any of the many python gui libs.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. I guess the easiest way would be to add a simple GUI just for Windows...

Comment: @The_Fallen, did you try the suggestion in issue 23057 to add a periodic task? @schlenk, the C runtime has a console control handler that raises `SIGINT` for Ctrl+C and `SIGBREAK` for other events. The `KeyboardInterrupt` is from Python's default handler, but you can replace it. For asyncio, `signal.set_wakeup_fd` was updated to support sockets on Windows, but for some reason the patch to implement a signal handler in the Windows event loop was never finalized and merged. I don't use asyncio, so I haven't had a reason to pick up the mantle.

Comment: No, I did not, I now just addes a simple window using pyqt. Works like a charm and the loop ends nicely when I close the window. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can implement kind of a cross-platform python signal handler in your python script that works on both Unix/Linux and Windows, python has a standard ***signal*** library, so you can do something like this

```
import asyncio
import signal


class GracefulExit(SystemExit):
    code = 1


def raise_graceful_exit(*args):
    loop.stop()
    print("Gracefully shutdown")
    raise GracefulExit()


def do_something():
    while True:
        pass


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, raise_graceful_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, raise_graceful_exit)

try:
    loop.run_forever(do_something())
except GracefulExit:
    pass
finally:
    loop.close()
```

It does not behave exactly the same on Windows and Linux due to the aforementioned platform differences, but for most cases it works okay on both platforms.

Comment: loop.run_forever take no arguments. (Did you mean run_until_complete?)
Also what happens to incomplete tasks here? Suppose I have task that needs to kill thread or subprocess when cancelled?

Comment: "Unlike signal handlers registered using `signal.signal()`, a callback registered with `loop.add_signal_handler()` is allowed to interact with the event loop." I am unsure about all the implications of this but I think this documentation fragment should be worth being highlighted in this answer. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler

Answer (score 2):

yet another version of multiplatform graceful exit

```
import asyncio
import signal

async def main():
    try:
        i=0
        while i<10:
            print('<Your app is running>')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            i +=1
    except asyncio.CancelledError: 
        for i in range(3):
            print('<Your app is shutting down...>')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    class GracefulExit(SystemExit):
        code = 1


    def raise_graceful_exit(*args):
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop)
        for t in tasks:
            t.cancel()

        loop.stop()
        print("Gracefully shutdown")
        raise GracefulExit()


    def do_something():
        while True:
            pass


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  raise_graceful_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, raise_graceful_exit)
    task = loop.create_task(main())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except GracefulExit:
        print('Got signal: SIGINT, shutting down.')
    if 1:
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=loop)
        for t in tasks:
            t.cancel()
        group = asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        loop.run_until_complete(group)
        loop.close()
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to call `loop.stop()` directly from a signal handler, at least not if we have any external events coming in. But I got it working by calling `loop.create_task(shutdown())` from the signal handler, and then `shutdown()` calls `loop.stop()`. Also, I guess `loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())` should be an easier way to cancel all pending tasks?

Comment: Missing `loop=` :  ` asyncio.gather(*tasks, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)`