# Catch CTRL+C and exit gracefully in Python with a multithreaded controller on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, keyboardinterrupt

I'm trying to create a **Windows** SMTP server in Python that uses the `aiosmtpd` library, which provides a multithreaded controller that listens on a TCP port for connections.

This code works perfectly:

```py
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller

class CustomSMTPServer:
    # Proof of concept
    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        print(f'> Incoming mail from \'{envelope.mail_from}\'')
        return '250 OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = Controller(CustomSMTPServer(), hostname='127.0.0.1', port=25)
    controller.start()

    # I would like to wait for CTRL+C instead of ENTER
    input(f'SMTP listening on port {controller.port}. Press ENTER to exit.\n')

    # ... and stopping the controller after the key has been pressed
    controller.stop()
```

I would like to modify it such as it doesn't wait for <kbd>ENTER</kbd> but for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead, without using a `while True` endless loop because this would eat CPU. It would be great to not use a lot of libraries imports, if possible.

Is there anything better than using `time.sleep(1)` inside the loop, as the `aiosmtpd.controller` is already running in its thread and the main thread is not doing anything useful, apart from waiting for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: Try to add `SIGINT` handler to loop `controller.loop.add_signal_handler(SIGINT, controller.stop)`. Imports: [`SIGINT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGINT).

Comment: it would help if you provided the CustomSMTPServer implementation (or the library it resides in). Otherwise the code can't be executed

Comment: @MarcinCuprjak Yes, you're right. I've edited the question.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I get `NotImplementedError`, due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45987985/2631300) probably?

Comment: @virtualdj, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337002/10824407) answer. You don't need to implement everything, just stop all tasks and loop itself.

Comment: @OlvinRoght But that answer is actually using a _while_ loop with `asyncio.sleep` (probably similar to `time.sleep`?) so it doesn't provide anything useful IMHO. In addition it uses *tasks* which are not necessary in my code, because `aiosmtpd.controller` is already using multithreading. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the signal module to catch the SIGINT (Ctrl+C) signal and stop the dispatcher. Here is an example:

```
import signal
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller

def stop_controller(signal, frame):
    controller.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = Controller(CustomSMTPServer(), hostname='127.0.0.1', port=25)
    controller.start()

    print(f'SMTP listening on port {controller.port}. Press Ctrl+C to exit.\n')

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop_controller)
    signal.pause()
```

Now the program will wait for the SIGINT signal instead of ENTER and will stop when the user presses Ctrl+C. The stop_controller function will be called when a signal is received and will stop the controller. The signal.pause() function waits for any signal, but does not consume CPU resources until a signal is received.

Comment: I found the `signal.pause()` in other answers, but it didn't work in my case. Is it available in Windows? If I run your code I get `AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'pause'`.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a CTRL+C signal instead of waiting for the user to press ENTER, you can try using the signal module:

```
import signal
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller

# Create a flag to indicate if CTRL+C signal has been received
ctrlc_received = False

# Define a signal handler for CTRL+C
def handle_ctrlc(signal, frame):
    global ctrlc_received
    ctrlc_received = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Register the signal handler for CTRL+C
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_ctrlc)

    # Start the SMTP controller
    controller = Controller(CustomSMTPServer(), hostname='127.0.0.1', port=25)
    controller.start()

    # Wait for CTRL+C
    print(f'SMTP listening on port {controller.port}. Press CTRL+C to exit.')
    while not ctrlc_received:
        pass

    # Stop the controller after receiving CTRL+C
    controller.stop()
```

Comment: Check CPU usage

Comment: This works, but the `while not ctrlc_received: pass` lines are equal to the `while True` in the question. They eat the CPU while waiting (you can see that 1 CPU of your PC goes to 100% while in there).